# How to extract capital letters from string before number in R

Tags: r, dataframe, substring, subset, extract

I have a dataframe with strings in a column. How can I extract only uppercase substrings before a number and add them to another column? An example is for DE, but there are many more country abbreviations and they always appear before a number.

```
TD<-data.frame(a=c("WHATEVERDE 11111","","Whatever DE 11111","DE 11111",""), 
           b=c("","What DE EverDE 1111","","",""),
           c=c("Whatever","","","","WhateverDE 11111"))
```

And I would like to create another column as follows:

```
> TD
                  a                   b                c     result
1  WHATEVERDE 11111                             Whatever         DE
2                   What DE EverDE 1111                          DE
3 Whatever DE 11111                                              DE
4          DE 11111                                              DE
5                                       WhateverDE 11111         DE
```

I tried to apply the solution:

```
sub("^([[:alpha:]]*).*", "\\1", "DE 11111") but is not universal.
```

Vector with abbreviations:

```
names<-c('AT','BE','DE','BG','CZ','DK','FR','GR','ES','NL','HU','GB','IT')
```

Comment: Do you have a vector of abbreviations that should be matched or is it non-specific ie. match to any uppercase letters before the digits and if any space?

Comment: YES, I can accept a vector with country abbreviations. They will always be in capital letters and, in my case, two letters.

Comment: Thanks, but will that be a vector of length > 50 or so?

Comment: The vector is not long, I added an example.

Comment: And what if the vector shows a three-letter country, e.g. IRL?

Comment: I updated the post.  It should work now.   From the `countrycode` package you can get the 2 letter abbreviations, which is used in creation of pattern

Comment: If it is a three letter, instead of `iso2c`, it would be `iso3c` column

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We loop `across` the columns, extract the 2 letter uppercase countrycode substring that precedes zero or more spaces and one or more digits, `coalesce` the output so that it returns the first non-NA extracted element per row

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(countrycode)
pat <- countrycode::codelist %>%
       pull(iso2c) %>% 
       na.omit %>% 
       str_c(collapse = "|") %>% 
       sprintf(fmt = "(%s)(?=\\s*\\d+)")

TD %>% 
   mutate(result = invoke(coalesce, 
     across(everything(), ~ str_extract(., pat))))
```

-output

```
                  a                   b                c result
1  WHATEVERDE 11111                             Whatever     DE
2                   What DE EverDE 1111                      DE
3 Whatever DE 11111                                          DE
4          DE 11111                                          DE
5                                       WhateverDE 11111     DE
```